# Printing changing values in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

someone I know came to me with some odd behaviour when printing a numpy array. He wanted to assert that his calculation of the autocorrelation is reasonably close using np.allclose(). But the test failed, if he did not print the array and worked if he printed the array beforehand.

Here is my example code I tried with Windows 10, python 3.7.2 (64bit) and numpy 1.16.1:

```
import numpy as np

def autocorrelation(data):
    """
    Input is an array of the form number_data * dimensions
    An example is shown when this cell is executed
    """
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    u = np.mean(data, axis=0, keepdims=True)
    std_dev = np.std(data, axis=0, keepdims=True)
    # std dev matrix
    std_mat = std_dev.T @ std_dev

    ## 1/|D| * sum {x elem D} ((x - u)/std_dev)^T * ((x - u)/std_dev)
    # (x - u)
    diff = (data - u)
    # (x - u)^T * (x -u)
    #A = diff.T @ diff
    #print(A)
    # pairwise division matrix std dev
    A = np.divide((diff.T @ diff),std_mat, where=(std_mat!=0))
    # print(A)

    # A/|D|
    return np.divide(A, data.shape[0])

test_data1 = np.stack([[1,2,3], [2,2,2]], axis=1)
cor1 = autocorrelation(test_data1)
real_cor1 = [[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]
print(cor1)
print(real_cor1)

test_data2 = np.stack([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], axis=1)
cor2 = autocorrelation(test_data2)
real_cor2 = [[1,1], [1,1]]
print(cor2)
print(real_cor2)

print("test3")
test_data3 = np.stack([[21.0, 160, 110, 3.90, 2.620, 16.46]
,[21.0, 160, 110, 3.90, 2.875, 17.02]
,[22.8, 108, 93, 3.85, 2.320, 18.61]
,[21.4, 258, 110, 3.08, 3.215, 19.44]
,[18.7, 360, 175, 3.15, 3.440, 17.02]
,[18.1, 225, 105, 2.76, 3.460, 20.22]], axis=0)
cor3 = autocorrelation(test_data3)
real_cor3 = np.corrcoef(test_data3, rowvar=False)
print("cor3:\n",cor3)
print(real_cor3)

assert np.allclose(cor1, real_cor1), "Wrong output: correlation should be \n {} \n for this data, is \n {}".format(real_cor1, cor1)
assert np.allclose(cor2, real_cor2), "Wrong output: correlation should be \n {} \n for this data, is \n {}".format(real_cor2, cor2)
assert np.allclose(cor3, real_cor3), "Wrong output: correlation should be \n {} \n for this data, is \n {}".format(real_cor3, cor3)
```

Formatting the code like this failed the first assertion. Rerunning the code seems to fix the issue of the failed assertion.

If I print A before returning it, not only the output gets rounded, the assertion does not fail at all.

In conclusion, I have two questions:

1.) Why does the `print(A)` lead to rounded numbers?

2.) Why does the assertion sometimes fail and sometimes does not fail?

Would be really happy, if somebody could provide me with an answer as I feel pretty stupid right now.

Have a great one.

E:

Specification: The problem probably lies within `A.__str__()` as this get's called by `print()`.

In conclusion, I have two similar questions:

1.) Why does the `A.__str__()` lead to rounded numbers?

2.) Why does the assertion sometimes fail and sometimes does not fail?

You can check out this [google colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ZpRHAt4BHEyw8TICCFaqdSbg2vZINJt_?usp=sharing) where the bug happens.

Comment: I just ran your code and it seems to pass every time for me.

Comment: Also, `print()` does not affect the value of the the variable you are printing. If you want to inspect the value up to a certain number of significant figures, use formatting for e.g. `print(np.array_str(A,precision=10))`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @VarunNayak, but why does print not work in predictible fashion then? I had scientific notation once and rounded values another go.

Can you specify your OS and the version of python and numpy you are using? We came to different results on different operating systems somehow.

Comment: Hello there, @VarunNayak, have you seen my latest edit? I added a colab notebook where the code failed.